# Display multiple same values only once while others are looping using ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular10

I have the following sample data set which comes from server.

```
[
    {
        subMenuId: 1,
        submenu: 'Users',
        menu: 'Administration',
        url: '/pms/admin/usrs-dsh',
        icon: 'fas fa-cogs',
    },
    {
        subMenuId: 2,
        submenu: 'Roles',
        menu: 'Administration',
        url: '/pms/admin/roles-dsh',
        icon: 'fas fa-cogs',
    },
    {
        subMenuId: 3,
        submenu: 'Menu Items',
        menu: 'Administration',
        url: '/pms/admin/menus-dsh',
        icon: 'fas fa-cogs',
    },
    {
        subMenuId: 4,
        submenu: 'Banks',
        menu: 'Administration',
        url: '/pms/admin/banks-dsh',
        icon: 'fas fa-cogs',
    },
    {
        subMenuId: 5,
        submenu: 'Branches',
        menu: 'Administration',
        url: '/pms/admin/branches-dsh',
        icon: 'fas fa-cogs',
    },
    {
        subMenuId: 6,
        submenu: 'Dashboard',
        menu: 'PD3',
        url: '/pms/pd3/dsh',
        icon: 'fas fa-cogs',
    },

];
```

And I want to display this data like this. But currently when displaying data main level values repeat with each sub level value.
**Expected Output**:
[image: Expected Output]

**My Output:**
[image: my output]

Html file:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let m of userPermissions;">
                        <td>
                            <label class="ml-3 form-check-label">{{m.menu}}</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input (change)="changeSubMenus($event, m.menu,m.subMenuId)" type="checkbox" class="ml-0 form-check-input">
                                <label class="ml-3 form-check-label">{{m.submenu}}</label><br>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

TS file:

```
getMenus(){
  this.userPermissions = this.adminService.allMenus;
  
  this.userPermissions.forEach((val) =>{
     // console.log(val)
     // TODO: remove multiple main level values and display sub level values with one main level value
  })
```

}

Is there any way to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the objects in the array to achieve the requirement you want. You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for that like below.

You need to have an object structure like the below, to make things simpler

```
modifiedMenu = [{
  menu: < Main Menu 1 > ,
  subMenu: [ < submenu item > , < submenu item > , ...]
}, {
  menu: < Main Menu 2 > ,
  subMenu: [ < submenu item > , < submenu item > , ...]
}, ...]
```

So, the original one is

```
userPermissions = this.menus.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  if (acc.length === 0) {
    acc.push(this.getModifiedMainMenu(ele));
    return acc;
  } else {
    const existedMenu = acc.find(m => m.menu === ele.menu);
    if (existedMenu) {
      existedMenu.subMenu.push(this.getSubMenu(ele));
      return acc;
    } else {
      acc.push(this.getModifiedMainMenu(ele));
      return acc;
    }
  }
}, []);

getModifiedMainMenu(obj) {
  return {
    menu: obj.menu,
    subMenu: [this.getSubMenu(obj)]
  };
}

getSubMenu(obj) {
  return {
    menu: obj.menu,
    subMenuId: obj.subMenuId,
    submenu: obj.submenu,
    url: obj.url,
    icon: obj.icon
  };
}
```

And in the template file, now you need 2 `ngFor`s to loop main menu items and respective submenu items like below

```
<tr *ngFor="let m of userPermissions;">
  <td>
    <label class="ml-3 form-check-label">{{m.menu}}</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div *ngFor="let subMenu of m.subMenu">
      <input (change)="changeSubMenus($event, subMenu.menu, subMenu.subMenuId)" type="checkbox" class="ml-0 form-check-input">
      <label class="ml-3 form-check-label">{{subMenu.submenu}}</label>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

### Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vxr5nw?file=src/app/app.component.html)